# Magick++ segfaults in thread

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads, imagemagick, magick++

Writing a scanning program. After it reads an image, it calls `convertToPDF()` and then reads the next image.  The program seg faults (`RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault: 11;`) when the Image is declared in the thread.  The same code works fine when run in the main thread, I moved it from `thrPDF` to `convertToPDF` to make sure.  So I'm thinking it's something to do with Magick++'s memory allocation that is over my head.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void ScanWindow::convertToPDF(string fileName)
{
   pthread_t convert;
   string* args = new string(fileName);
   void *thrPDF(void*);
   pthread_create(&convert,NULL,thrPDF,args);
}

void *thrPDF(void* a)
{
   string* fName = (string*) a;
   string newFile = fName->substr(0,fName->length()-3) + "pdf";

   Magick::Image img(*fName);  // this is the line that seg faults
   img.magick("pdf");
   img.write(newFile);

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Here is the call stack:
omp_get_max_threads(?)
GetOpenMPMaximumThreads inlined
AcquirePixelCache(?)
AcquireImage(?)
Magick::ImageRef::ImageRef(?)
Magick::Image::Image(?)
thrPDF(?)
_pthread_start(?)
thread_start(?)

Comment: This isn't the cause of your crash, but you're leaking memory -- you need to `delete fName` at the end of `thrPDF` to avoid leaking that object (after you're done using it, of course).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Also just to clarify for other readers, I tried the Image constructor with a string constant and it still segfaulted.  So fName is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: What's the call stack on the segfault?

Comment: Looks like a bug with OpenMP (https://gist.github.com/yipdw/1120721), maybe.  You could try disabling OpenMP, though that'll hurt performance on a multicore system.

Comment: That worked! I had to reconfigure ImageMagick with the --disable-openmp flag and then rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not already being done, you should be invoking InitializeMagick(NULL) (or InitializeMagick(*argv)) in your main/original thread prior to using the rest of the API.  This may help cure some issues related to threading.  With Magick++ included with GraphicsMagick, this is an absolute requirement in modern releases.